# how to change TLabel caption with regular intervals in a loop?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

I want to make a TLabel caption show the items of a TListbox with regular intervals in a loop.

In `Listbox1: TListbox` I have  these items:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
```

and I have a `Label1: TLabel` that I want to show each item of `Listbox1` in turn for a periode of 4 seconds. After the last item is shown, it should return to show the first one.

I have no idea how to do it but I tried with this code.. but it isn't working

```
var
  i:integer
begin
  for i:=0 to Listbox1.Items.count do    
    Label1.Caption := Listbox1.items[i];
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what *like like it repeat the item string in listbos.items[1] or [2] or [3] 'till the max of it and repeat again 'till the beginning* means. Can you [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking?

Comment: @KenWhite i am really sorry since i am not good at speak. i already edited the post please check it. or let me get this straight. i got 4 items tring in TListBox and i got TLabel so i want label1.caption is following TListbox string one by one and repeat the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a place to store the index of the displayed item, until it is time to change to the next one. So, create a field of type `integer` in the `private` section of the form and call it `IndexCounter`

You also need something to set the pace of how often the label is changed. Drop a `TTimer` on the form. Set its `Interval` property to 4000 (it counts in milliseconds).

With the added timer selected, switch Object Inspector to show Events, and doubleclick in the entry field for `OnTimer`. A procedure for the event is created for you:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

Fill in code to increment the `IndexCounter` and use integer division remainder function (`mod`) to get a value in the range 0..ListBox1.Count-1.

> `IndexCounter := (IndexCounter + 1) mod ListBox1.count;`

Add code to show the listbox item with index `IndexCounter`.

> `Label1.Caption := ListBox1.Items[IndexCounter];`